How to Log User Login and Logout Times in Firestore and Display Them in a Table in Flutter?
I'm working on a Flutter app where I need to track user login and logout times, along with additional user information like full name, ID, and compound location. I want to display this information in a table on a separate screen.
Here's what I've implemented so far:
Logging Login Time:
In my Signin screen, I log the login time when the user successfully logs in:
final userDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('signing').doc(credential.user!.uid);

// Log login time
await userDocRef.set({
  'FullName': FullNamecontroler.text,
  'ID': IDcontroller.text,
  'compound': compoundcontroller.text,
  'login': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  'logout': null,
}, SetOptions(merge: true));


Logging Logout Time:
I also log the logout time when the user logs out:
void _logout() async {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  if (user != null) {
    final userDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('signing').doc(user.uid);

    // Log logout time
    await userDocRef.update({
      'logout': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
    Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, Signin.screenroute, (route) => false);
  }
}


Displaying Data in a Table:
On my Tablescreen, I fetch and display this data in a table:
class Tablescreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String screenroute = 'Tablescreen';
  const Tablescreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Tablescreen> createState() => _TablescreenState();
}

class _TablescreenState extends State<Tablescreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this, initialIndex: 0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _controller,
          tabs: [
            Tab(text: "Table"),
            Tab(text: "Select Table"),
            Tab(text: "Sort Table"),
          ],
        ),
        title: Center(
          child: Text(
            " Daily Reports",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Container(
          child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('signing').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
              } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
                return Center(child: Text('No data available'));
              } else {
                final data = snapshot.data!.docs;
                return DataTable(
                  columns: <DataColumn>[
                    DataColumn(label: Text("FullName")),
                    DataColumn(label: Text("login")),
                    DataColumn(label: Text("ID")),
                    DataColumn(label: Text("compound")),
                    DataColumn(label: Text("logout")),
                  ],
                  rows: data.map<DataRow>((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    final Map<String, dynamic> userData = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

                    // Format timestamps
                    String formatTimestamp(Timestamp? timestamp) {
                      if (timestamp == null) return 'N/A';
                      return timestamp.toDate().toString();
                    }

                    return DataRow(
                      cells: <DataCell>[
                        DataCell(Text(userData['FullName'] ?? '')),
                        DataCell(Text(formatTimestamp(userData['login'] as Timestamp?))),
                        DataCell(Text(userData['ID'] ?? '')),
                        DataCell(Text(userData['compound'] ?? '')),
                        DataCell(Text(formatTimestamp(userData['logout'] as Timestamp?))),
                      ],
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Questions:
How do I correctly log the login ,logout times with compoundlocation ,fullname and ID  in Firestore?
How can I update the Firestore document with the logout time when the user logs out?
Is there a better approach to handle this tracking?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
to track user login and logout times, along with additional user information like full name, ID, and compound location


How can I update the Firestore document with the logout time when the user logs out?

If you want to track multiple login/logout times, you'll end up either with an array of a map. An array would work like this:
await userDocRef.update({
  "authActivity": FieldValue.arrayUnion([{
    "action": "logout",
    "timestamp": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  }]
});

So every time you run this code, it adds an element to the authActivity array field that indicates that the user logged out at this time.

However, the Firestore document does not seem to be updated correctly, and I'm not seeing the expected result

Since you seem to have taken the approach that I suggested in the new question you posted, see What should I do when someone answers my question?
